# How to open local html file by Selenium Safari WebDriver on macOS?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver, safaridriver

I have tried:

```
safariDriver.get("file:///Users/pathToMyHtml/index.html");
safariDriver.get("/Users/pathToMyHtml/index.html");
```

but none of them worked. I use Java and macOS Sierra.
(If I open a page from http:// it's working)

Comment: What is the error? It looks OK on my machine. macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: Actually there is no error message. The SafariDriver instantiation works properly. But when I use the get method, it simply doesn't open the local file.

Comment: What is the version of macOs?

Comment: 10.12.5 macOS Sierra

Comment: Can you post full code? On my machine I ran `driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('file:///Users/aFolder/500.html')` and it worked properly.

Comment: Sure. I use this code:
SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("resources/SafariDriver.safariextz"));
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("file:///Users/myUser/Development/index.html");

The SafariDriver.safariextz is downloaded from here:
https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.48/

Comment: Are you using Safari 10/ Selenium 3?

Comment: My Safari version is 10.1.1 and I use selenium-java with version: '2.41.0'

Comment: Can you update Selenium to 3.4? I can see the package on [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java). On Selenium 3, you don't need the extension anymore. I think it may solve this issue.

Comment: I found that this local path reference is unsupported:
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3773 . However I tried 3.4 as you mentioned and it's working now. :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is Selenium version. You need to upgrade Selenium to version 3++. 
It works fine on my machine with Selenium 3.4.

See issue at: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3773